# @Named annotation with qualified names (e.g. path.beanName) separated by periods

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, el

Can I annotate a class with `@Named("path.beanName")` and access it in EL as `${path.beanName}`?

It seems to work fine in JBoss EAP 6.4, but I would like to confirm it's part of the specification (I can't find anything about it in CDI 1.0 or JSP specifications, maybe it's somewhere else), or if it works as expected in other application servers at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDI specification 1.0 does not seem to mention this so if you truly are in such an ancient version, you cannot rely on it being portable. However, starting with CDI 1.1, you already can.

Following links are to CDI 1.2 (as it is mor readable than 1.1 and in regards to bean names unchanged) - CDI specification, [2.6 Bean Names](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#names):

> A bean may have a bean name. A bean with a name may be referred to by its name in Unified EL expressions. A valid bean name is a period-separated list of valid EL identifiers.

Then there is also more in [5.3 EL Name Resolution](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#name_resolution) and few other scattered references in the spec which can be found using `CTRL + C`.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. If I'm going to migrate to something else, it would certainly be newer than CDI 1.0, so I guess I'm safe enough.